# ClassCastException after upgrading from Spring Boot 2.1.9 to 2.2.1 (Spring Integration)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have a Spring Boot project that uses Spring Integration. I upgraded from Spring Boot 2.1.9.RELEASE to 2.2.1.RELEASE and now I get an exception when my application starts up.

The exception is logged at DEBUG level and my application still seems to work without problems.

Is this a bug in the new version of Spring Integration?

Stack trace:

```
2019-11-09 11:57:28.983 DEBUG 12776 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.h.s.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper   : Exception trying to extract interface

java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.demo.mail.ConfirmationMailTransformer cannot be cast to class org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised (com.demo.mail.ConfirmationMailTransformer is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @24ed52ef; org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.getTargetClass(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:985) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.findHandlerMethodsForTarget(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:711) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:294) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:215) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:219) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.<init>(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MethodInvokingTransformer.<init>(MethodInvokingTransformer.java:43) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.TransformerFactoryBean.createMethodInvokingHandler(TransformerFactoryBean.java:53) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractStandardMessageHandlerFactoryBean.createHandler(AbstractStandardMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:142) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.createHandlerInternal(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:198) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:186) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:60) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:171) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:135) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:127) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:427) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:173) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1451) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
```

This is what my class `ConfirmationMailTransformer` looks like:

```
package com.demo.mail;

import com.demo.model.RegistrationEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ConfirmationMailTransformer {

    public String toMailText(RegistrationEvent event) {
        return "Email text";
    }
}
```

It's configured using Spring Integration XML configuration:

```
<!-- Transform payload to text to be used as the body of the e-mail -->
<int:transformer ref="confirmationMailTransformer" method="toMailText"/>
```

Java version (AdoptOpenJDK 11 on Ubuntu 18.04):

```
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.4+11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

Plain Spring Boot application generated from https://start.spring.io with Spring Boot starter for Spring Integration, running with `mvn spring-boot:run`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by "unnamed module" in the exception message, you are using Java's module system. Judging by `RestartClassLoader` in the exception message, you are using Spring Boot's DevTools. At the time of writing, this combination is unsupported and known not to work. There's an [open enhancement request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12832) that you may want to subscribe to.

Regardless of the possibly unsupported combination of the module system and DevTools, the change in behaviour appears to be due to [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/ae2be1bb23e0a03d7ebd59412e69001cad940b7e) in Spring Integration. Previously, there was a check for `AopUtils.isAopProxy(targetObject)` being `true` before an attempt to cast to `Advised` was made. This check is no longer made. That should be benign although slightly ugly if you have debug logging enabled. You may want to raise a [Spring Integration issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues) so that the team can investigate and reinstate the check if needed.

Comment: No, I am not using the Java module system, just plain old classpath. I am running it on Java 11 and I am also using DevTools. The exception wasn't there with 2.1.9.

Comment: Are you sure? I don't recall seeing mentions of unnamed modules unless the module system was being used. Perhaps you could update your question with some more details about the JVM you're using and how you're launching your application so that it's possible to recreate exactly what you're doing?

Comment: I will that over weekend. Thank you for raising! Apparently we don’t have an appropriate test...

Comment: OK. This is not a stack trace. this is a *DEBUG* message: `DEBUG 12776 --- [  restartedMain]`. How does it fail your application? I guess we could move it into a `TRACE` though or really add some check before trying to cast into an `Advised`...

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thanks for looking at it. It doesn't fail my application (as I said above), - but I do have this ugly stack trace since upgrading to 2.2.1.

Comment: Well, I don’t think you are going to use DEBUG in production. So, you are save so far

Comment: @ArtemBilan yes, it's not super-urgent, it doesn't break my application, but I can imagine that it will alarm people if they have debug logging on. Do you want me to create an issue on GitHub as Andy suggests?

Comment: No. That’s ok. I’ll PR it soon

Comment: I decided to push the fix directly to `master`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/a6fb891a817dacc1af9fa238fa0797623ea65416. It is so simple and obvious that doesn't deserve any review :smile: